# What intent do I use for firebase email verification

Tags: android, firebase

I have successfully sent a verification link to the user's email. Upon link is sent, i display "Verify Email" on the UI. What I want is for user to be able to go directly ( if possible) to the email client so that they can click the link and verify.
My question is, how do i open that email client?
Or at least, open an intent where user can choose an email client to open.

What i dont want is open an intent to write an email with subject and body and all, because clearly that is not my  intention and all the help i see on the internet is all about it.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to open default email app you can use this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```